# Define date format for @RequestBody entity without @JsonFormat

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

For example I have the following class

```
public class Profile {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    //seter, getter
}
```

In controller I use this class as @ResponseBody parameter

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profiles")
public class ProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createProfile(@RequestBody Profile newProfile) {
        //...
    }

}
```

If I sent POST request to `/profile` with the following JSON it works fine

```
{
    "dateOfBirth": "21-01-1985"
}
```

How can I achieve this behavior without annotating `Profile#dateOfBirth` class with `@JsonFormat` or any other annotation? I want to use this entity for different date formats so I need to define date formats outside of `Profile` class.

Comment: Can you make all the properties in Profile class as String and then convert to specific date format where you are planning to use that field.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson custom deserialization.
Theres a few ways to handle it. This blog seems to have a good answer.
https://www.sghill.net/how-do-i-write-a-jackson-json-serializer-deserializer.html

Comment: I would need to annotate `Profile` class with `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSerialize`. But I don't want `Profile` class to be to be dependent on anything. I need to define date format for `Profile#dateOfBirth` dynamically.

Comment: An alternative would be to have a another class that depends on Jackson, and you convert your dependency-less class to the class dependent on Jackson

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@JsonProperty("obj-name")` . For example

```
public class Profile {    
    @JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    //seter, getter
}
```

Json request will be

```
{
"dateOfBirth": "21-01-1985"
}
```

`@JsonProperty()` will directly map the particular json object field. So now you can request with any date format. and If you want to validate some date format best and suggested way is `Custom Annotation`

Hope It will be very helpful...

Cheers...

Comment: The answer is incorrect, @JsonProperty is to map the field name, instead of taking certain format and deserialize to LocalDate